# Facebook Graph - Get a user's game requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

first of all, I'd like to mention that I've been looking for this answer everywhere for more than 2 days and couldn't figure it out, even though many other ppl have already asked the same question.

So, here's the thing: As part of a facebook app I'm developing, I need to get all apps(games actually) requests(invitations if you will) that were sent to the user(the one logged in to my app via fb), and doesn't matter which app/game sent it. I mean, ALL apps other than mine, assuming, of course, my app won't know which app has sent the request to the user.

I've already tried many combinations of the "/me/apprequests" graph api, and all I get is an empty json.

So, any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your application you will need

> manage_notifications

Permissions to do this.

You can reed full documentation about that in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1